# How to aggregate values of variables for every 10 bins of another variable

Tags: r, group-by, aggregate

I am working on a vehicle data & I intend to compute number of times a driver applied breaks per every 10 KM. I have the following sample data:

Harsh Breaking Event is a measurement which explains if he applied a harsh break or accelerated fast at that point in time

```
CAR ID        Date             Harsh Event (0/1)      Odometer
xx        2014-01-01 06:23:59              1             1213  
xx        2014-01-01 06:24:00              0             1213  
xx        2014-01-01 06:24:01              0             1213  
xx        2014-01-01 06:24:02              1             1213
```

Output should look like

```
CAR ID             Date             Harsh Event (0/1)          Odometer
XXX            2014-01-01 06:27:23              23                   1223
```

I tried with the following code, but its not working

```
Low-val<-min(data$Odometer)

High-val<-max(data$Odometer)

breakpoints<-seq(Low-val, High-val, by = 10)

output<-data%>%

    group_by(car)%>%

    aggregate(Breaking_Event~cut(Odometer,breaks=breakpoints),sum)
```

How can i generate such a count for all cars? Please note every car has its on odometer readings.

UPDATE:

The below code worked for me.

temp<-data%>%group_by(car id) %>%

mutate(Bins=cut(Odometer,breaks=seq(min(Odometer), max(Odometer), by = 10),labels = F))

temp_new<-temp_new %>%

group_by(car, Bins) %>%

summarise_all(funs(mean, sum))

Comment: You could try grouping by both interval and car at the same time.

Comment: I am sorry, i did not get what you mean by interval...do you mean the breakpoints..

Comment: Always providing enough data is important to provide a solid solution, but here is a try using `iris` dataset, `iris%>%group_by(Species) %>% mutate(Breaks=cut(Sepal.Length,breaks=seq(min(Sepal.Length), max(Sepal.Length), by = 10),labels = F)) %>% group_by(Species,Breaks) %>% summarise(Breaking_Event=sum(Petal.Length))`. I hope I get you wright.

Comment: When I tried to run with your code, I am not getting the sum of breaking events for every 10 KM(bin) but I am getting whole aggregated sum... also noted your advise on the data will try to post more data going forward. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Coolsun you're most welcome. Next time use `@User Name` when you reply to comments so the user can get notify and reply ASAP. Also, I encourage you to post your UPDATE as an answer and accepted if it solves your problem, so your question appears as an answered question which may help future readers.

Comment: Sure will do that. Thanks @A.Suliman . I am new to this still learning so pardon my ignorance.